# Error in google App engine when creating a dataset in bigquery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am developing an App Engine application to make queries from BigQuery.  When I create a bigquery instance and after that I want to either create a dataset or obtain reference to a dataset the following error occurs. This only happens when I deploy the app on App Engine but when I use the local app engine sdk to test my app I dont have any problems

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init> (BasicRetryingFuture.java:77)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture (DirectRetryingExecutor.java:75)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries (RetryHelper.java:53)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getDataset (BigQueryImpl.java:227)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getDataset (BigQueryImpl.java:218)
at com.example.Edmonds.myapplication.backend.MyServlet.doGet (MyServlet.java:75)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:717)
```

The part I try to do so is as follows:

```
InputStream ios = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/BackendTestMac-f8739513cc27.json") ;
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setServiceAccount(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/BackendTestMac-f8739513cc27.json"))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://backendtestmac.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();

BigQuery bigQuery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("backendtestmac").setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(ios)).build().getService() ;

 String datasetId = "my_dataset_id";
 Dataset dataset = bigQuery.create(DatasetInfo.newBuilder(datasetId).build()) ;
```

Comment: Have you tried with the Java 8 runtime for App Engine? Or is this Java 7? I believe the Java 7 version of App Engine may be incompatible with some of the Google Cloud client libraries, so if Java 7 is a requirement you may have to use the Google API client libraries https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/bigquery/v2

Comment: @TimSwast How can you tell a Google Cloud client library with which Java version is compatible ?

Comment: How do you run the project locally ?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the standard app engine tutorial and experienced a similar exception:

On page:

```
    Error: Server Error
    The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
    Please try again in 30 seconds
```

In server Logs

```
Error for /create
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init>(BasicRetryingFuture.java:77)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:75)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:53)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:148)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:141)
    at com.example.getstarted.util.CloudStorageHelper.uploadFile(CloudStorageHelper.java:65)
    at com.example.getstarted.basicactions.CreateBookServlet.doPost(CreateBookServlet.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.example.getstarted.util.DatastoreSessionFilter.doFilter(DatastoreSessionFilter.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
```

When uploading images it worked fine running locally, but broke when promoted to appspot

HOWEVER, after the user authentication section, **once I was logged in, I didn't get the error**.  If was anonymous - got that error.  Potentially it was broken in a recent patch.  As I don't think they would have released that core tutorial without mentioning it.

Tutorial link is: https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started-appengine-standard/tutorial-app

Maybe this helps.  Lemme know if you find out any more!

Answer (score 0):

You should check the classpath of your app. Most likely you have an old version of Guava on your CP